# Is there somewhere accurate SPICE model for Analog Devices AD5246 I2C adjustable resistor?

Tags: spice, multisim

Question already in title - is there?

Because I haven't seen official model on Analog.com.

Because I asked AI to create such model for me, and it spit this:

> Sure, here's a SPICE model for the AD5246 resistor from Analog Devices that you can use in SPICE simulators:

> ```
> * AD5246 256-Position I2C-Compatible Digital Resistor
> * Model created by ChatSonic, a creative AI writing assistant built by Writesonic
> *
> * Terminal connections:
> *   1. Terminal A
> *   2. Wiper Terminal
> *   3. Terminal B
> *
> * SPICE model:
> .subckt AD5246 A W B
> Ra W Ra 1
> Rb W Rb 1
> Rw W Rb 2
> Rw Ra Rb 10k
> .ends AD5246
> ```

> To use this model, simply include it in your SPICE netlist and connect it to your circuit as you would with any other resistor. The model includes three terminals: A, W, and B, which correspond to the resistor's two end terminals and its wiper terminal. Note that the model assumes a 10kΩ resistance range for the AD5246. If your specific AD5246 has a different resistance range, you will need to adjust the values of the resistors in the model accordingly.

And I think this model is kinda sus.

According to [functional block diagram of AD5246 from official documentation](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5246.pdf), it should have:

> 1. VDD Positive Power Supply.
> 2. GND Digital Ground.
> 3. SCL Serial Clock Input. Positive edge triggered.
> 4. SDA Serial Data Input/Output.
> 5. W W Terminal.
> 6. B B Terminal

But the above model has only three terminals.
No grounding, nor two serial inputs and positive power supply included into model.
It looks incomplete to me.

I'm total beginner in electronics, so anyone could give me some easy to understand hints, how to custom create such SPICE model of AD5246.

Or what components to use in MultiSim Education Edition, to design it by my own?

Comment: It's a very simple model. How accurate model you need is the next question, because you don't know how to model the chip unless you already know how to model it.

Comment: AI can't create models for semiconductor devices without having some way of actually hooking up to said device and measuring things. It's no different than a human in that respect. Or said AI would need to have access to proprietary data somehow exfiltrated from the chip manufacturer. I now expect an influx of these kinds of questions - because people do believe in magic. And AI is about as non-magical as it gets - sorry to disappoint. Some AI taught EE, not creative writing (lol) might create a model based on publicly available details - but that would be extremely specialized AI indeed.

Comment: The subcircuit it gave you is simple enough (4 resistors) to draw out yourself and see how it works.  I think it tried to give you a subcircuit for a generic potentiometer, but did a horrible job of it.  For starters there are two definitions for `Rw`, and any SPICE engine should throw an error.  Anyway, I think you need to clarify and focus what exactly you need to do with such a SPICE model.  You rarely need to simulate an entire I2C interface in SPICE.  So you need to ask yourself "what are you trying to measure or characterize?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't, use a [variable resistor](https://www.multisim.com/content/TmCTwT3tYQSYvyAUNBdvuQ/variable-resistor/) and make sure that you account for the voltage range (a digital resistor's inputs are limited in the voltage they can take, VDD +0.3V) also realize that there is some leakage current.